# Which Mathematica version created/saved notebook

Tags: notebooks

If a notebook is opened in a version of Mathematica that is older than the version that created/saved it, an alert window is displayed stating "This notebook was created in a more recent version of the Wolfram System..." But it does not show the specific version.

How can a user determine what version of Mathematica created/saved a notebook?

Comment: Nope. That appears to be showing the current FrontEndVersion. However, I've discovered that viewing the notebook as text shows a line near the top with the information that looks like (* CreatedBy='Mathematica 13.1' *)

Comment: The Front End overwrites the option value in the file when the notebook is loaded.  But it is stored in the file.

Comment: Try `Options[Import[<filename>, {"NB", "Notebook"}], FrontEndVersion]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 - that worked. Submit as answer and I'll accept.